# Solution MAXMIN problem on hackerrank is giving a timeout

Tags: java, arrays, greedy

My solution seems to timeout certain test cases (im sure its a large input).

Here is the problem:
[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyuwt.png)

What is a way to better my solution that it doesnt timeout?

```
Sample Input 

7
3
10
100
300
200
1000
20
30
Sample Output 

20

My code:
public class Solution {

    // Complete the maxMin function below.
    static int maxMin(int k, int[] arr) {
            //int[] subarr =new int [k];
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            int unfair = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int diff;
            for(int i = 0; i<arr.length ; i++){
                    for(int j = i+k-1; j<arr.length; j++){
                            diff = arr[j]-arr[i];
                            System.out.println(j);
                            if(unfair>Math.abs(diff)){
                                    unfair = Math.abs(diff);
                            }
                    }
            }

            return unfair;


    }
```

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Thank you,
I have been trying to edit it properly.